# Bucle ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS (Redirección PHP)

Tags: php

Tengo este código PHP que detecta el idioma del navegador y redirige al usuario a la versión de mi web en ese idioma. Si la versión no existe, se redirige al usuario a la versión en Inglés. Mi idioma principal es Español, cuya ruta es la raíz del dominio.

```
<?php
$accept_languaje = !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'] : 'es';
$main_languaje   = substr($accept_languaje, 0, 2);
switch ($main_languaje):
    case 'es':
        exit(header("Location: https://ejemplo.com/"));
    case 'en':
        exit(header("Location: https://ejemplo.com/en.php"));
    case 'pt':
        exit(header("Location: https://ejemplo.com/pt.php"));
endswitch;
if (false !== strpos($accept_languaje, 'es')) {
    exit(header("Location: https://ejemplo.com/"));
}
if (false !== strpos($accept_languaje, 'en')) {
    exit(header("Location: https://ejemplo.com/en.php"));
}
if (false !== strpos($accept_languaje, 'pt')) {
    exit(header("Location: https://ejemplo.com/pt.php"));
}
exit(header("Location: https://ejemplo.com/en.php"));
?>
```

Pero sucede que si el usuario habla español, el script lo vuelve a mandar a la misma ruta (https://ejemplo.com/) y causa el error `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`.

Cómo puedo decirle al script que si el usuario habla español **no haga la redirección?**

Gracias de antemano.